# Get all Ethereum contract transactions as Truffle instances

Tags: node.js, ethereum, web3js, truffle

I'm trying to create a web server looks for a specific data value of an Ethereum contract as new transactions are made. I want it to watch for new transactions, if that transaction is of the specified contract type then do a contract call to get a data value from the contract.

I know that I can get all transaction data by doing the following, but I don't know how to make a contract call using this, and the data in txInfo.input is combined with multiple data values.

```
for (var i = startBlockNumber; i <= endBlockNumber; i++) {
    web3.eth.getBlock(i, function(err, blockInfo) {
      if (!blockInfo) {
        return;
      }
      for (var j = 0; j <blockInfo.transactions.length; j++) {
        var tx = blockInfo.transactions[j];
        web3.eth.getTransaction(tx, function(err, txInfo) {
          log(txInfo);
        });
      }
    });
}
```

In order to make contract calls I tried using the truffle-contract library but I only seem to be able to access the latest transaction that occurred. In the following code, the getMyValue function in my solidity contract returns the value from the latest transaction but the allEvents watch functionality never gets called even if this is running while a new transaction occurs.

```
App.contracts.myContract.deployed().then(function(instance) {

  const allEvents = instance.allEvents({
    fromBlock: 0,
    toBlock: 'latest'
  });
  console.log(allEvents);
  allEvents.watch((err, res) => {
    console.log(err, res);
  });

  instance.getMyValue.call().then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
}).catch(function(err) {
  console.log(err.message);
});
```

I'm running this as a node server with:

- truffle-contract v3.0.4
- web3 v0.20.1
- express v4.16.3

Comment: Are you expecting `getMyValue` to throw the event or is the event thrown somewhere else completely? There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with how you're using `allEvents`, and that approach WILL give you all events that have occurred (both previously in the range of block numbers specified and new ones coming in). Something else seems to be going on.

Comment: @AdamKipnis Your response helped me realise that I was misunderstanding what events are and I eventually found a way to accomplish what I wanted. Basically, I thought my truffle instance contract calls were events, but now I see events are part of the solidity contract language. For my task I decided to give one party the ability to create a contract (truffle instance.new), the other party looks for contract creation transactions and uses the truffle.at method with the transcript contract address.